# VLC Stream Size

Tags: linux, webcam, vlc-media-player

VLC can open my webcam using the `Media` → `Open Capture Device` menu. However, how do I control the webcam capture resolution?  It seems to be stuck at 640x480.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do it with the `--v4l2-width=1280 --v4l2-height=720` options proir to opening the stream.